# Firestore rules based on path component and other collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to establish a rules, where user would only be able to perform operations on Chat messages after they have made a purchase of one of the services.

My database structure looks like this:

I have purchases collection: `purchases/{purchaseId}` which contains `buyer_id` field.
I also have messages collection: `/channels/{purchaseId}/thread/{threadId}`.

I want to allow CRUD operations if the users in `thread` are the same as `buyer_id` from purchases collection, in `purchaseId` document.

This is what I've tried, using current user's ID (auth) for now. This doesn't work, either.
Ideally, I would substitute `request.auth.uid` with the field from the document I am trying to access, but this would do for now.

```
match /channels/{purchaseId}/thread/{threadId} {
    allow read, create, update, delete: if get(/databases/{database}/documents/purchases/{purchaseId}).data.buyer_id == request.auth.uid;
}
```

I am getting the standard permissions error. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You syntax is wrong when defining the path. Try this:

```
match /channels/{purchaseId}/thread/{threadId} {
    allow read, write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/purchases/$(purchaseId)).data.buyer_id == request.auth.uid;
}
```

Substituting `request.auth.uid` with the field from the document:

```
match /channels/{purchaseId}/thread/{threadId} {
    allow read, write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/purchases/$(purchaseId)).data.buyer_id == resource.data.buyer_id;
}
```